# What mistakes with this query?

Tags: postgresql

```
$query = "select (select count(a.serial_no) from tra2 a where a.model_no = ".$id." and a.flag = cast(3 as character varying) + (select count(a.serial_no) from stk a where a.model_no = ".$id." and a.trans_id is  NULL)as qty)";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->result();
```

When i run the query

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: ...ck a where a.model_no = K258 and a.trans_id is  NULL)as qty)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of the quest must be:

```
 ...a.trans_id is  NULL)) as qty"
```

Currently You have some like this

```
select (select 1 + 2 as qty)
```

but You want

```
select (select 1 + 2) as qty
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `''` (quotes) on your `WHERE` clauses. I guess the data type is `VARCHAR` so you have to use quotes in your query

Like this
`.... WHERE a.model_no = '" . $id . "' AND ...`